# MonoDevelop reports my platform incorrectly on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, windows, mono, operating-system

I'm using Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with MonoDevelop 5.9.6. I have created a console application and this is the only code:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine (new PlatformID());
}
```

However, in the console, this is the output:

```
Win32S
```

Why is it detecting my platform incorrectly? I'm clearly not using Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PlatformID` is an enumeration from `System`, not a class you can instance so I'm not sure how your code even complies.

If you want OS Version and/or Platform, here is how you can obtain it:

#### Code Snippet:

```
var os = Environment.OSVersion;
var pid = os.Platform;
Console.WriteLine($"{os}");
Console.WriteLine($"{pid}");
```

#### Output:

```
Unix 15.6.0.0
Unix
```

Comment: Without the "new" the code does not compile and Mono throws the error "Expression denotes a `type`, where a `variable`, `value` or `method group` was expected" and [this page](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8472/help-with-error-expression-denotes-a-type-where-a.html) told me to add the "new". While your answer doesn't explain why "new PlatformID()" returns "Win32S", it does tell me how to get the platform, so thanks!